# How to get django to authenticate during unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

i am trying to test an ***unauthenticated** / **UNAUTHORISED** user accessing an API in django. in the API i have the following code

```
class myAPIView(TimezoneAwareMixin, RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    model = mymodel
    serializer_class = mymodelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsCompanyActive, HasRole)
    get_roles = ('mymodel-view',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Allow only users within a company to see only their objects
        """

        return mymodel.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.active_company)
```

then in my test i have inherited TestCase and attempt the following

```
client = client_class() # no headers so its anonymous
client.get(url)
```

but i get the following during testing

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'attribute_name'
```

im expecting a 403 Forbidden or a 401 Unauthorized

instead of a traceback

how can i get the correct response

Comment: Sounds like your test is working, and it reveals that you have a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
c = Client()
c.login(username='fred', password='secret')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.login

And you should modify your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def get_queryset(self):
    ...
```

Comment: i want to test ***UNAUTHORISED**** access, so i need to get a 403 or 401 it all works great when the user is authenticated

Comment: I think you need add @login_required decorator to get_queryset method.

Comment: yes the decorator workd, its returning a 401 now. but can you explain why the  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,.. did not return that first before the request hit the code

Comment: It happens because you overrided get_queryset method. You can read about it here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/, section DjangoModelPermissions

Comment: Thanks Eugene! this helped a great deal, i have 300 tests to write and want to automate as much as possible